# How to get the day, year, hours, min Individually from date format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"?

Tags: android, datetime

I am doing a programme that stores the present time and date in `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` this format. and I am storing it in database as a string. when i am collecting the data i need the individual values like day, year, min, seconds etc.. how can i do this?

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String now = formatter.format(new Date());
```

Thank you,

Comment: What's the issue, you're using the right class

Comment: How do you collecting the data, through database or java code?

Comment: Your question is unclear... you want them to be entered separately by the user or you want to separate them coming out of the database?

Comment: i am storing the current date when user logins, but at the time of passing i want to split it..

Comment: I found it easier to store everything in a DB as a "time in millis".

Comment: @JoelSkrepnek is it possible to get the sec, fractional seconds from time mills?

Comment: The granularity is milliseconds.  Pull the value out of the DB, create a Calendar object based on it, then use the 'get' method with the field set to MILLISECOND.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm suggesting that you store times in the DB as "timeInMillis".  In my experience it simplifies code and it allows you to compare times values to eachother.

To store a time:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // current time
long timeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
mDb.saveTime (timeInMillis); // adjust this to work with your DB
```

To retrieve a time:

```
long timeInMillis = mDb.getTime();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis (timeInMillis);
int milliSeconds = calendar.get(MILLISECOND);
//etc
```

Answer (score 32):

Just use parse instead of format :

```
String dateFromDB = "";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date yourDate = parser.parse(dateFromDB);
```

And then you can can read any field you want using java.util.Date & Calendar API :

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(yourDate);
    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //Day of the month :)
    calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND); //number of seconds
//and so on
```

I hope it fits your needs

Comment: it is showing the error 'java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2012-05-11T18:25:55:250GMT'

Comment: try to parse it just after the format. => parse the output of the format to see if the issue comes from the database.

Comment: Anyway, try to parse the output of the format function. Also, make sure your date format is compliant with rules.

Comment: i did not get this,  "parse the output of the format function"

Comment: sorry for my bad english. I mean try Date yourDate = parser.parse(parser.format(new Date());

Comment: It is working fine now for new date.. But not for my date entered? Y?

Comment: Your date has : instead of . between 55 and 250. It may be the reason it doesnt work. But now you know you to parse the date :)

Comment: @wolverine try this SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SZ");

Answer (score 1):

There are these methods available to get the individual parts of a date

```
getDate()
getMinutes()
getHours()
getSeconds()
getMonth()
getTime()
getTimezoneOffset()
getYear()
```

Comment: These method was deprecated in API level 1. As of JDK version 1.1, To be replaced by using the following for ex: Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.

Answer (score 1):

Try using : int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

Here,

- Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY gives you the 24-hour time.
- Calendar.HOUR gives you the 12-hour time.