# Date object from simple string - Java and Android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

specific date is "**2013-11-12**".

I want to extract day, month and year from above date. Please let me know how can I extract?

Comment: check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: u can use split method

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551955/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()`.

**Example :**

```
String mydate="2013-11-12"; //year-month-day

String myyear=mydate.split("-")[0];  //0th index = 2013
String mymonth=mydate.split("-")[1]; //1st index = 11
String myday=mydate.split("-")[2];   //2nd index = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date testDate = null;

try {
      testDate = sdf.parse("2013-11-12");
}
catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
}

int date= testDate.getDate();
int month = testDate.getMonth();
int year = testDate.getYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create date object from your date string first, like...

```
String yourDateString = "2013-11-12";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date yourDate = parser.parse(yourDateString);
```

Now create Calender instance to get further information about date...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourDate);
int months = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND); 
// and similarly use calender.getXXX
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @Bhavin: appriciated...:)

Answer (score 1):

you can use substring method to extract the particular characters from the above string like:

```
String year=date.substring(0,4);   //this will return 2013
String month=date.substring(5,7);  //this will return 11
String day=date.substring(8,10);   //this will return 12
```

Comment: your one cannot be correct if "2013-1-1"

Comment: it will be set as default 2013-01-01 or if you know the date will be in this order you can change it as String year=date.substring(0,4);   //this will return 2013
String month=date.substring(5,6);  //this will return 1
String day=date.substring(7,8);   //this will return 1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Calendar`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2013-11-12"));
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) Class.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011"));// all done
```

Now you can use this `cal` Object to do whatever you want. Not just the date, month or year. you cam use it to perform various operations, such as `add month`, `add year` etc...